# How to change mysql.sock?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have installed mysql through binary installation and followed below steps
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-installation.html

Right now sock files are craeted on /tmp/mysql.sock when mysql service is started.

I want to know which configuration files need to be edited to change the path of mysql.sock

I tried the following steps to change mysql.sock path from /tmp/mysql.sock to /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

1.I tried to enter socketpath in /etc/my.cnf

```
socket =/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

2./etc/init.d/mysql

```
basedir=/var/lib/mysql
datadir=/var/lib/mysql/data
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Can anybody help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 4):

Setting these variables in my.cnf should work just fine (Tested locally, Ubuntu 10.10).

```
[mysqld] 
datadir=/var/lib/mysql 
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Just make sure you're restarting MySQL Service?

Below is what I did, this is on Fedora (Since you're using RHEL this should more mimic your setup):

```
[root@rudi /]# ls /var/lib/mysql/
ibdata1  ib_logfile0  ib_logfile1  mysql  mysql.sock
[root@rudi /]# ls /var/run/mysqld/
mysqld.pid
[root@rudi /]# nano /etc/my.cnf 
[root@rudi /]# service mysqld restart
Stopping mysqld:                                           [  OK  ]
Starting mysqld:                                           [  OK  ]
[root@rudi /]# ls /var/lib/mysql/
ibdata1  ib_logfile0  ib_logfile1  mysql
[root@rudi /]# ls /var/run/mysqld/
mysqld.pid  mysql.sock
```

The only thing that I changed was `socket=` this time, and restarting still worked fine.

Are you sure that you're not editing `socket` within the `[client]` section of `my.cnf`? It must be under the `[mysqld]` section.

Comment: yeah i have restarted the mysql service. whether my.cnf is the only file we need to specify the path ? or any other file ?

Comment: I've updated my answer with exactly what I did, and a few more comments. Does this help at all?

Comment: If you are seeing this message in `/var/log/mysql/errors.log`: `130308 13:37:30 [ERROR] Can't start server : Bind on unix socket: Permission denied`, you might need to edit `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld`, and change the path of the socket file in there as well.