# Configure phpMyAdmin to use a different socket

Tags: mysql, sockets, phpmyadmin

I am trying to install phpMyAdmin on a machine running ubuntu, for reasons of compatibility I have am running a backdated binary version of MySQL (5.5.54). It is essentially running okay, I can access databases from php clients using localhost.

When I try to use the auto configure script included with phpMyAdmin, I get the following error:

```
 ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket d '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")
```

Effectively there is no folder at the  location `/var/run/mysqld`. In file 'my.cnf' the socket is set as `socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock` I have not yet found how to alter this default, it would seem that this is a possible mismatch, there is also a second file, added on installing phpMyAdmin called `my.cnf.server`.

Should I look to change the socket, or, perhaps configure phpMyAdmin manually?

I would appreciate some help.

This post seems related:

[Help to change mysql.sock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832266/help-to-change-mysql-sock#5832300)

Though I was wondering if it is possible to change the socket that phpMyAdmin is looking for. Was the default changed in later versions of mysql; Currently running 5.5.54 for compatibility reasons.

Comment: Humm, is this systemd related I wonder?

Comment: Started reading 'UNIX network programming' ; determined to get a clearer understanding ...

Answer (score 4):

configure PMA to use the correct socket. in config.inc.php replace

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
```

with

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '/tmp/mysql.sock';
```

Comment: It worked. Thou it is one of the most unintuitive things I ever seen :) Replacing 'host' with 'socket'. And it has no helpful comments in config there.

Comment: I fond out that this was not needed anymore if I did a `service php-fpm restart` after editing socket in `/etc/my.cnf`, PHP takes it from there, but I just had to restart PHP FPM in order for this value to reflect in phpinfo() and in PhpMyAdmin too. I will add an answer about this.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get around this by switching phpMyAdmin from socket connection to TCP connection:

`vi /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` and enter the IPAddress instead of `localhost`

I also had to change the dbserver and dbport in `vi /etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php`

Comment: phpMyadmin (phpMyAdmin-4.4.15.10-2.el7.noarch) stopped to work when I updated to mariadb 10.214 (MariaDB-server-10.2.14-1.el7.centos.x86_64). I spent a lot of time fixing it until I saw to this: change localhost to IP address. (BTW, No idea what it is config-db.php)

Comment: I am using 2 MySQL instances on my Mac - one on 127.0.0.1 and another using sockets. The sockets is the default one which is being used by MAMP PRO. I wanted to connect to the TCP one via phpMyAdmin and found this solution. (Using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found out that `PHP` and `PhpMyAdmin` actually **do get** their socket values from `/etc/my.cnf` just that you need to do a `service php-fpm restart` before `mysqli.default_socket` is reflected in phpinfo() and phpmyadmin.

in `/etc/my.cnf`

**Careful about the** `datadir` value, in my example I specified these to completely move MySQL directory.

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/SSD-2/mysql
socket=/SSD-2/mysql/mysql.sock
mysqlx_socket=/SSD-2/mysql/mysqlx.sock
```

Then **important**:

```
service php-fpm restart
```

So in this case, it was **no need to edit** `/etc/php.ini` and `/etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php` anymore .